# How to create crosswalk table to match people with different id's?

Tags: sql

I have 2  tables with the same information including: id, name, address, zip code, phone number. However, The ID's are different for the same person on each table. How can I create a crosswalk table to match the id's based on the rest of the information?

EX)

Table1

```
ID   | Name     | Address     | Zip   | Phone
-----------------------------------------------------
1111 | John Doe | 123 Fake St | 12345 | 123-456-7890
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Table2

```
ID   | Name     | Address     | Zip   | Phone
-----------------------------------------------------
2222 | John Doe | 123 Fake St | 12345 | 123-456-7890
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Desired Crosswalk

```
Table1ID | Table2ID
---------------------
1111     | 2222
---------------------
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with `JOIN`s?  You can `JOIN` on all of the fields that you expect to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join the two tables on the columns that match like:

```
SELECT Table1.ID AS Table1ID, Table2.ID AS Table2ID
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Name = Table2.Name 
  AND Table1.Address = Table2.Address 
  AND Table1.Zip = Table2.Zip 
  AND Table1.Phone = Table2.Phone
```

Here I joined on all columns, you would have to adjust it to the ones that actually match...

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. I didn't know you could use 'and' 'or' operators with joins.

Answer (score 0):

As is explained [in this article and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366780/how-to-do-an-inner-join-on-multiple-columns), you can use JOIN to match all columns in both tables through table aliases:

```
SELECT t1.id Tab1Id, t2.id Tab2Id 
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 on tb1.name = t2.name 
INNER JOIN t2 tb2_1 on t1.address = tb2_1.address 
INNER JOIN t2 tb2_2 on t1.zip = tb2_2.zip 
INNER JOIN t2 tb2_3 on t1.phone = tb2_3.phone
```

Comment: This is incorrect syntax; see **jpw**'s answer for the correct syntax.

Comment: Nice, @jpw answer is more simple and clear, i'm going to clean some views, tks!