# Multiple column left join from table1, table2

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: table1,table2 as given below

```
table1:
id   name
1    tamil
2    english
3    maths
4    science

table2:
p1 p2 p3 p4 stat name
1  2  4  3   A   raja
2  3  4  1   A   maha
```

my expected output is

```
p1       p2       p3       p4
tamil   english   science  maths
english maths     science  tamil
```

can some one help me to find out the exact query.That should use left outer join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do an INNER JOIN on multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366780/how-to-do-an-inner-join-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: 1. See normalisation. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Strawberry: what you said is correct. But this was the existing DB in my project. I just working on it  that's all.

Comment: @Strawberry. what do you mean ?If I had a penny... this is not the place to tease or to play with others

Comment: it's part of a phrase used when a frequently cited excuse is given as a reason for not doing something properly

Comment: @Strawberry that you can say it openly like this. please don't teats others if you are a genius.

Comment: I'm not a genius, so I think I'm exempt from such prohibition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select P1, t1.Name,P2, t3.Name, P3,t4.Name, P4 , t5.Name From Table2 T2
left join table1  t1 on 
T2.P1 = T1.Id
left join  table1  t3 on 
T2.P2 = T3.Id
left join  table1  t4 on 
T2.P3 = T4.Id
 left join  table1  t5 on 
T2.P4 = T5.Id
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t1.name AS p1, t2.name AS p2, t3.name AS p3, t4.name AS p4
FROM table2 tbl2 INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON tbl2.p1 = t1.id
INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON tbl2.p2 = t2.id
INNER JOIN table1 t3 ON tbl2.p3 = t3.id
INNER JOIN table1 t4 ON tbl2.p4 = t4.id
```

Click the link below for a running demo.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ee9c0/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.pr, s.name, s1.name, s2.name, s3.name
FROM subjects s, subjects s1, subjects s2, subjects s3, time_t t
WHERE s.id=t.pr AND s1.id=t.p2 AND s2.id=t.p3 AND s3.id=t.p4
```

Comment: It is not apparent which type of `JOIN` this will result in.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Explanations add clarity, insight, and provide opportunities to learn, so future visitors can solve their own related issues.