# Performing inner join on two tables with two fields instead of one

Tags: android, sqlite, join, inner-join

I have a database with 4 tables.

**settings**

**movies**

**trailers**

**reviews**

```
final String SQL_CREATE_MOVIE__SETTING_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MovieContract.MovieSettings.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            MovieContract.MovieSettings.COL_MOVIE_SETTING + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL " +
            " );";

    final String SQL_CREATE_MOVIE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_KEY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_BACKDROP_PATH + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_ORIGINAL_LANGUAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_ORIGINAL_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_OVERVIEW + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_VOTE_AVERAGE + " REAL NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_VOTE_COUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_POSTER_PATH + " TEXT NOT NULL, "  +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +

            // Set up the location column as a foreign key to location table.
            " FOREIGN KEY (" + MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_KEY + ") REFERENCES " +
            MovieContract.MovieSettings.TABLE_NAME + " (" + MovieContract.MovieSettings._ID + "), " +

            // To assure the application have just one weather entry per day
            // per location, it's created a UNIQUE constraint with REPLACE strategy
            " UNIQUE (" + MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_DATE + ", " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_KEY + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";

    final String SQL_CREATE_TRAILER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MovieContract.TrailerEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_TRAILER_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_ISO_369_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_KEY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_SITE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_SIZE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +


            // Set up the movie_id column as a foreign key to movie table.
            " FOREIGN KEY (" + MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" + MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + ") " +

            " UNIQUE (" + MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + ", " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_TRAILER_ID + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";

    final String SQL_CREATE_REVIEW_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MovieContract.ReviewEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            MovieContract.ReviewEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            MovieContract.ReviewEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.ReviewEntry.COL_REVIEW_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.ReviewEntry.COL_AUTHOR + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.ReviewEntry.COL_CONTENT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.ReviewEntry.COL_URL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +

            // Set up the movie_id column as a foreign key to movie table.
            " FOREIGN KEY (" + MovieContract.ReviewEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" + MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + ") " +

            " UNIQUE (" + MovieContract.ReviewEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + ", " +
            MovieContract.ReviewEntry.COL_REVIEW_ID + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";
```

I want for now to inner join the the trailers tables into the movie table. So the new trailers table should have the following columns.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|_id  |movie_id |poster_path  |id  |iso_639_1  |key  |name  |site  |size  |type  |
```

Both *movie_id* and *poster_path* columns belong to the movies table. I perform the inner join as

```
sTrailerByMovieIdQueryBuilder.setTables(
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ON " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + 
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + " = " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + 
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + " AND " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + 
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_POSTER_PATH
        );
```

But I get this table

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|_id  |movie_id |id  |iso_639_1  |key  |name  |site  |size  |type  |
```

The *poster_path* column is missing. I did something wrong in my inner join but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: After AND you mentioned only one table column. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366780/how-to-do-an-inner-join-on-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0):

The reason why poster_path column is missing is because you failed to call another inner join in your query.

Currently, your query looks like this:

```
trailers 
INNER JOIN movies
ON trailers.movie_id = movies.movie_id
AND movies.poster_path
```

Your query should look like this:

```
... 
INNER JOIN movies m1
ON trailers.movie_id = m1.movie_id
INNER JOIN movies m2
ON trailers.poster_path = m2.poster_path
```

Comment: Also I don't declare poster_path in my trailers table.

Comment: It's an alias for your table. You can also do `movies AS m1`

Comment: Could you include the code for the complete query? Maybe you just forgot to include _poster_path_ from the SELECT statement?